# get_the_terms issue on foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I want to show taxonomy name in post. I use foreach loop but it does not show any thing to me.

here is my code.

```
<?php

    global $post;
        $foo_home_url = site_url();

        $url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        if(strpos($url, 'foo_cat')){
            $foo_bc_cat = get_the_terms( $post->ID , FOO_POST_TAXONOMY );
    ?>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $foo_home_url; ?>">Home</a></li>
    <?php
                    foreach($foo_bc_cat as $foo_tax_cat){
    ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($foo_tax_cat->slug, FOO_POST_TAXONOMY) ?>"><?php echo $foo_tax_cat->name ?></a></li>
    <?php
                    }
    ?>
            </ul>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

Any idea.

Comment: What debugging have you done here? Is the `if` statement working? What is `$foo_bc_cat` set to? Are you even going into the `foreach`? What is in `$foo_tax_cat` inside the foreach?

Comment: According to wordpress codex `FOO_POST_TAXONOMY` should contain the slug of your terms, probably in your post there is no term with that slug, try to change it with `post_tag` and check if it works, it should retrieve all post tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code

```
<?php
global $post;
    $foo_home_url = site_url();

    $url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    if(strpos($url, 'foo_cat')){
        $foo_bc_name = get_queried_object()->name;
?>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $foo_home_url; ?>">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($foo_tax_cat->slug, FOO_POST_TAXONOMY) ?>"><?php echo $foo_bc_name; ?></a></li>
        </ul>
<?php
    }
?>
```

instead of this code

```
<?php

    global $post;
        $foo_home_url = site_url();

        $url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        if(strpos($url, 'foo_cat')){
            $foo_bc_cat = get_the_terms( $post->ID , FOO_POST_TAXONOMY );
    ?>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $foo_home_url; ?>">Home</a></li>
    <?php
                    foreach($foo_bc_cat as $foo_tax_cat){
    ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($foo_tax_cat->slug, FOO_POST_TAXONOMY) ?>"><?php echo $foo_tax_cat->name ?></a></li>
    <?php
                    }
    ?>
            </ul>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
```